# Play mid-roll with exoplayer while playing audio in android

Tags: android, audio, ads, media, exoplayer

We have a podcast app where we play audio ads before any episode plays. We build a playlist with 2 items - the first item is the ad URL and 2nd is the episode. Now the requirement is to show mid-roll in between the episode playing. The client is not using any IMA or XML vast URL to get ads. They have audio URLs as ads like episodes. Already checked https://exoplayer.dev/ad-insertion.html but no option is fitting in my requirement. Can you please suggest me here?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an ads wrapper I use.

```kotlin
private fun wrapNonNullAdsToMediaSource(
        adsUrl: String?,
        viewGroup: ViewGroup?,
        mediaSource: MediaSource,
        onComplete: (MediaSource) -> Unit
    ) {
        if (player.mediaItemCount != 0) initializeAdsLoader()
        val isWrapped = ifNotNull(adsUrl, viewGroup, imaAdsLoader) { url, view, loader ->
            onComplete(AdsMediaSource(
                mediaSource,
                DataSpec(Uri.parse(url)),
                listOf(url, mediaSource.mediaItem.mediaId),
                DefaultMediaSourceFactory(context)
                    .setLocalAdInsertionComponents({ loader },
                        { view }),
                loader
            ) { view })
            true
        }
        if (isWrapped != true) onComplete(mediaSource)
    }
```

In your case, you need to use the second media source in the function because it puts ads at the beginning. This is a starting point: viewGroup being your exoplayer parent container and a bonus onComplete that runs no matter which error, nulls or unfetchable urls. You can nuke the `if (player.mediaItemCount != 0)` because my use case involves using the player for something else without a decodable media source

You can then use it like this

```kotlin
       player.run {
            wrapNonNullAdsToMediaSource(
                adsUrl = playbackOptions?.adsUrl,
                viewGroup = platformListener?.getPlayerViewGroup(),
                mediaSource = mediaSource ?: hlsMediaSource
            ) { source ->
                setMediaSource(source)
            }
            prepare()
            playWhenReady = true
        }
```